# Microsoft AD FS

Tags: android, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

I am a newbie and I am making an android and web app that uses Spring Boot REST APIs (microservices) in the backend to load data.

I am trying to implement Microsoft SSO. Users are added by my client in AAD in a specific group.

The user opens the App. If first time user then redirects to Microsoft Login. Once the user logs in, the token is received. I validate this token in APIs to authorize the user.

My question: Let's say my client removes one user from the company group. Now next time the same user opens the app must be redirected to logout(from all apps) since the user is not supposed to access the resources.

Is SAML or OAuth2 of any use here(for validating. I know either is required to get token)? I have not yet decided on the language to be used so any solution is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are not dynamic.

To get a new token you have to login again.

There is nothing in SAML or OAuth2 that really addresses this.

The title says "ADFS" but then you refer to "AAD"?

Assuming AAD, you should do this via conditional access.

Then if the user is not a member of the group. AAD will not allow access.